# I installed qemu on WSL, but I don't see the binaries in /usr/bin - help?

Tags: software-installation, qemu

I ran this command on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS running on WSL:

```
me@mymachine:~$ sudo apt-get install qemu
```

Its output follows.  It is suspicious that it only installed 123kb, surely qemu is more than that.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  qemu
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
Need to get 14.3 kB of archives.
After this operation, 123 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 qemu amd64 1:4.2-3ubuntu6.10 [14.3 kB]
Fetched 14.3 kB in 1s (27.7 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package qemu.
(Reading database ... 32104 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../qemu_1%3a4.2-3ubuntu6.10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking qemu (1:4.2-3ubuntu6.10) ...
Setting up qemu (1:4.2-3ubuntu6.10) ...
```

However, I don't think it's actually installed, as I don't see the qemu binaries?

```
me@mymachine:~$ ls /usr/bin/q*
ls: cannot access '/usr/bin/q*': No such file or directory
```

Can anyone assist?  I am extremely new to Linux.  Thanks.

Comment: QEMU does run on Windows; you don't need WSL. Using QEMU on top of WSL means one VM running on top of another VM, so you may not get great performance from it.

Comment: I have a qemu workflow in Windows that I'm moving to Ubuntu as part of my quest to learn Linux.

Answer (score 4):

These days qemu is just a dummy package, with functionality split out among many packges.  run

```
apt-cache show qemu
```

for more information.
Try installing qemu-kvm for the hardware assisted version.

Installing qemu-kvm will actually install qemu-system-x86_64 and running kvm is like running qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm. For example, to create a 12G (max expansion) virtual machine (myvirt.img) from iso file whatever.iso:

```
qemu-img create myvirt.img -f qcow2 12G  
kvm -m 750 -cdrom whatever.iso -boot d myvirt.img
```

See man kvm for more information.

Comment: Well, so I did that, but I don't understand the output.  Let's say I want to install `qemu-system-x86_64` - how would I install that?  (EDIT: Am installing qemu-kvm and that appears to be doing something, although I don't know what kvm is)